# Pivot table excel or R

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table

My data looks like this on excel:

```
Genename ID1 ID2 ID3
Gene1   R   H   R
Gene1   R   H   R
Gene1   H   R   H
Gene2   H   R   H
Gene2   R   R   H
Gene2   H   R   R
Gene2   R   R   R
```

I would like to create a column with the total number of individuals with at least one H per gene.
So, it should look like this;

```
Genename Het
Gene1 3
Gene2 2
```

I have hundreds of gene so I need an automated way to get these counts.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to provide the original data in a better format. Is each one a column? and is it stored in a data.frame?

Comment: also, wouldn't gene1 have 4 H's in this case?

Comment: Yes it is a dataframe. I am sorry for the bad format. I am not interested in the total count of Hs per gene, but the total number of individuals with at least one H per gene.

Comment: Very pertinent information to add to your post and not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'Genename', get a logical index for `any` values that are 'H' in each column, get the `sum` within `summarise` and then we use `rowSums` to get the expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Genename) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(sum(any(.=='H')))) %>% 
   transmute(Genename= Genename, Het = rowSums(.[-1L]))
   Genename   Het
#    (chr) (dbl)
#1    Gene1     3
#2    Gene2     2
```

---

Or as @aosmith mentioned `distinct` would be an option after converting the 'wide' to 'long' format with `gather`.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, Var1, Var2, -Genename) %>% 
            group_by(Genename, Var1) %>%
            distinct(Var2) %>%
            group_by(Genename) %>%
            summarise(Het= sum(Var2=='H'))
```

#### Update

If we need the count of IDs with no 'H' and at least one 'R' per 'Genename'

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(Genename) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(all(.!='H') & any(.=='R'))) %>% 
     transmute(Genename=Genename, Het= rowSums(.[-1L]))
#   Genename   Het
#     (chr) (dbl)
#1    Gene1     0
#2    Gene2     1
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I actually need to have per gene the counts of individuals with at least one H. So, in mine case for Gene1 will be 3 and for Gene2 2. An individual can have more than one H, but I don't really take this into account. So, I am afraid I need a different formula.

Comment: Gene2 has only two individuals with H values. ID2 has no H values for gene2.

Comment: Is it possible by changing your first code to have the counts of individuals per gene with at least one R, but no H at all?

Comment: @VasoGene The condition based on the example showed, will give 0 for Gene1 and 1 for Gene2.  Is that the expected one?  Is this based on each row or the same as the previous condition?  The logic is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
res <- data[,list("Genename"=Genename,"Het"=rowSums(data=="H")>0)]
res <- res[,list("Het"=sum(Het)),by=Genename]

> res
#   Genename Het
#1:    Gene1   3
#2:    Gene2   3
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I actually need to have per gene the counts of individuals with at least one H. So, in mine case for Gene1 will be 3 and for Gene2 2.

Comment: @VasoGene well then Gene2 should have 3 then... please see my edits

Comment: But for Gene2 only two individuals (ID1 and ID3) have H values.

Comment: you need to make this way more clear in the question next time

Comment: @akrun it's not anymore, he should give you the credit